# Why doesn't forever restart node process if i kill it

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-14.04

i have installed forever in ubuntu 14.04 ec2 instance with command

sudo npm install forever -g

then i run the command **forever start server.js** following the instruction in [**nodejitsu blog**](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/)

**forever list** command shows the process id e.g 8673

if i kill that process using command **kill 8673** forever doesn't restart the node server.
But as per that blog post it must restart the server [stopping and restarting with forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/#stoppingandrestartingwithforever)

why does this happen and how to run node server continuously with forever ?? any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Try with your app throwing an unhandled exception and ensure it restarts (the purpose of forever).  It seems like it should stop on an explicit stop (kill) by handling SIGTERM message.

Comment: also check usage: there's a killSignal option -   '  --killSignal     Support exit signal customization (default is SIGKILL)',
  '                   used for restarting script gracefully eg. --killSignal=SIGTERM',

Comment: Thanks for commenting i throw an unhandled error . and my node server did not crash with forever. but it crashes with node server.js command.

Comment: This is proabably not the issue, but make sure your process runs at least as long as the --minUpTime option before killing, otherwise it will not restart it...